# Rolling calculations in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to model an amortising loan account in R using data table. Each row represents one month. Each month there is a repayment or an advance of funds, and an interest charge based on the previous month's balance.

For example:

```
> loan <- data.table(loan.age = seq(0:9), payment = c(5000, -rep(100,9)))
```

I can't see an easy way of adding the interest and balance columns. For an interest rate of 1% per month, the interest should be 0.01 times the previous month's balance, and the new balance should be the previous month's balance plus the current month's interest plus the current month's payment (which is normally negative). In pseudocode:

```
this_balance = last_balance + last_balance * 0.01 + this_payment
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
> loan
    loan.age payment interest balance
 1:        0    5000     0.00 5000.00
 2:        1    -100    50.00 4950.00
 3:        2    -100    49.50 4899.50
 4:        3    -100    48.99 4848.49
 5:        4    -100    48.49 4796.98
 6:        5    -100    47.97 4744.95
 7:        6    -100    47.45 4692.40
 8:        7    -100    46.92 4639.32
 9:        8    -100    46.39 4585.71
10:        9    -100    45.87 4531.58
```

I can solve the problem with a for loop, but it's unworkably slow over a large portfolio. For context, a 300 month loan is 100 times faster using the annuity formula than  a for loop (2s per loan vs 20ms).

I've tried joining the table to itself and I've also tried the shift() function that's new in Data Table 1.9.5, but I can't work out a way of forcing the calculations to be carried out from top to bottom so that the new balance ripples down the table.

My code currently works out the balance in each period using some financial maths derived from the annuity formula, but that approach won't work if interest rates change part way through the loan.

Thanks.

Edit: I count this problem as solved. Solution 2b) from 
G. Grothendieck below gives a generic solution that both works for this simple case and can be expanded to more complex scenarios.

Comment: Regarding the `interest` column, do you have a formula?

Comment: "the interest should be 0.01 time the previous month's balance, and the balance should be the previous month's balance plus the current month's interest." - that's not the case in your example. Please fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the worked example was correct but my narrative was incomplete. I've corrected the description and added a line of pseudocode to show how the maths works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1)** Try `filter`:

```
loan[, c("interest", "balance") := 0][, 
     balance := c(filter(payment, 1.01, method = "recursive"))][,
     interest := c(0, diff(balance) - payment[-1])]
```

giving:

```
> loan
    loan.age payment interest  balance
 1:        1    5000  0.00000 5000.000
 2:        2    -100 50.00000 4950.000
 3:        3    -100 49.50000 4899.500
 4:        4    -100 48.99500 4848.495
 5:        5    -100 48.48495 4796.980
 6:        6    -100 47.96980 4744.950
 7:        7    -100 47.44950 4692.399
 8:        8    -100 46.92399 4639.323
 9:        9    -100 46.39323 4585.716
10:       10    -100 45.85716 4531.574
```

**Note:** The last line could alternately be written:

```
         interest := .01 * c(0, balance[-.N])]
```

or in the development version of data.table:

```
         interest := .01 * shift(balance, fill = 0)[[1]]]
```

**2) Reduce**  Another possibility is:

```
f <- function(balance, payment) payment + 1.01 * balance

loan[, c("interest", "balance") := 0][, 
     balance := Reduce(f, payment, accumulate = TRUE) ][,
     interest := c(0, diff(balance) - payment[-1]) ]
```

**2a)** or if there is a `rate` column and it is known that `payment` is constant except for the first value (as in the question) then the following works. Note that we have made the `rate` column constant but the following still works even if `rate` varies as long as the assumption of a constant `payment` holds:

```
loan$rate <- .01
g <- function(balance, rate) loan$payment[2] + (1 + rate) * balance

loan[, c("interest", "balance") := 0][, 
     balance := Reduce(g, rate[-1], init = payment[1], accumulate = TRUE) ][,
     interest := c(0, diff(balance) - payment[-1]) ]
```

**2b)** This allows both `payment` and `rate` to vary:

```
loan$rate <- .01
h <- function(balance, i) loan$payment[i] + (1 + loan$rate[i]) * balance

loan[, c("interest", "balance") := 0][, 
     balance := Reduce(h, .I[-1], init = payment[1], accumulate = TRUE) ][,
     interest := c(0, diff(balance) - payment[-1]) ]
```

Comment: What is the := operator?

Comment: Its part of data.table.  From R, `library(data.table); help(":=")`

Comment: That works really well for the simple case that I've described. However, I also want to add a column for interest rate to allow for rates to change throughout the life of the loan. I can't see any way of achieving that with filter - using a vector as the second argument doesn't apply each element of the vector to each element of the loan.

Comment: Have added a second approach.

Comment: Woah! Apart from a slight typo (extra } symbol) in your first example, this is absolutely perfect. In particular 2b) gives a clear, expressive, generic solution that I can use to calculate various other rolling statistics for the loans. I haven't yet tested it for performance but it's a tool I'll definitely be using in a wide variety of circumstance. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have removed stray `}` .  I wouldn't think that `Reduce` would be as fast as `filter` as the key portion of `filter` is in C but for `Reduce` the key portion is the R function provided which is called repeatedly.

Comment: Reduce is fast enough. I can't make a proper comparison as I don't have access to my work server from home, but my 2011 macbook can process a loan in 5ms using method 2b). I shouldn't have any scalability problems with this solution.