# Combining flow payments to get daily balance

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with `data.table` trying to combine two pieces of information:

1. List of transactions each day to a given account
2. Balance of each account on a common, known day.

So the object I've got in hand can be boiled down to something like:

```
dt<-data.table(id=c(1,2,3,3,3,3),
               posting=as.Date(c("2013-12-24","2013-10-09",
                                  "2013-12-22","2013-12-10",
                                  "2013-11-12","2013-10-09")),
               balance_change=c(-57,-150,-145,-145,-145,-145),
               total_due=c(57,1570,11255,11255,11255,11255),
               key=c("id","posting"))
```

Which gives

```
> dt
   id    posting balance_change total_due
1:  1 2013-12-24            -57        57
2:  2 2013-10-09           -150      1570
3:  3 2013-10-09           -145     11255
4:  3 2013-11-12           -145     11255
5:  3 2013-12-10           -145     11255
6:  3 2013-12-22           -145     11255
```

The `total due` column includes all payments up to AND INCLUDING `2013-11-05`.

I'd like to create the `balance_at_date` column (which gives, for each date, the balance just prior to the transaction posting) in the simplest way possible; my current solution is rather protracted so I won't include it for now. The end goal is:

```
   id    posting balance_change total_due balance_at_date
1:  1 2013-12-24            -57        57              57
2:  2 2013-10-09           -150      1570            1720
3:  3 2013-10-09           -145     11255           11400
4:  3 2013-11-12           -145     11255           11255
5:  3 2013-12-10           -145     11255           11105
6:  3 2013-12-22           -145     11255           10960
```

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT

Here's what I'm doing so far; is there no better way to do this?

```
dt[posting>as.Date("2013-11-05"),
   balance_t:=cumsum(balance_change)-balance_change+total_due,by=id]
setorder(dt,id,-posting)
dt[posting<=as.Date("2013-11-05"),
   balance_t:=cumsum(-balance_change)+total_due,by=id]
setorder(dt,id,posting)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106726/rolling-calculations-in-r/28109338#28109338

Comment: can't reproduce dt with your data set

Comment: whoops, typo. should be `=` not `:=`; fixed

Comment: @G.Grothendieck could you ellaborate? I'm not seeing an exact parallel, though the `filter` function is good to have in my repertoire. The real bugbear is that there are payments before and after the date to which `total_due` is correct, and I'm not seeing a simple way to convert this to a time series.

Comment: Please add your current method so other people don't waste their time re-creating it.

Comment: and what exactly don't you like about your solution?

Comment: having to resort twice on two keys is on the slow side; if this could be avoided my code will run faster (important because I do this repeatedly)

Comment: it seems to me the key impediment is that `cumsum` only works "down" vectors, which is why we need to resort. I tried getting a solution along the lines of `cumsum(rev(x))` but with no breakthroughs. maybe someone else can have more luck?